# How to query a regular queryable WebApi endpoint with Breeze?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

Is it possible to use breeze to query an endpoint that is neither a controller with the breeze attribute or odata endpoint with metadata? Suppose we have a controller like this:

```
public class PersonsController : ApiController
{
    private AppContext db = new AppContext();
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Person> Get()
    {
        return db.People;
    }
}
```

I've enable filtering through query paramaters and would like to use the Breeze library to retrieve data, the example below fails because breeze tries to query api/metadata and there is no such metadata of course for this controller.

```
'use strict';
var serviceName = "api/";
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "WebApi" });
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
// would like a GET api/persons?$orderby=LastName&$skip=50&$top=10
var qry = breeze.EntityQuery.from('persons').orderBy("LastName").skip(50).take(10);

manager.executeQuery(qry).then(function (data) {
   //expecting data.results to contain the filtered/sorted set of Persons
});
```

Are non-breeze/odata api controllers supported for querying with breeze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any breeze DataService you can tell breeze not to expect metadata for the service.

By default breeze does expect to get metadata from the service so you will need to tell breeze not to by setting the DataService's 'hasServerMetadata' to false.  Something like this:

```
    var dataService = new DataService({
        serviceName: "aaa/bbb/myService",
        hasServerMetadata: false
    });

    return new EntityManager({
        dataService: dataService,
    });
```

If you do this, then you will also need to describe the metadata on the client directly.  See http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand for how to do this. If you do not describe the metadata then breeze will treat the results of any queries as anonymous types and not merge the results into the local EntityManager.